# Toggle Attribute Fields

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have what appears to be a simple question, but which I can't seem to determine an answer myself.  I have attributes in the polygons which represent multiple points over time (say January has a value of 1000, February has a value of 900, etc...)

I would like to know if there is an easy way to display/toggle only January time points, or February time points, etc.  I could theoretically create a layer for every month, but this is an impractical solution because the file would become too large.

The ultimate goal would be to export the map using qgis2web, and let the user toggle the month he/she wishes to see, with the corresponding attribute displayed.

Comment: Haven't used qgis2web yet, but what you mention is possible in QGIS by setting a layer filter. E.g., for January you would set this filter in `yourLayer-->Properties-->General-->Filter`: `"your_field_name" = 1000`.

Comment: You could create a style for each month and then 'toggle' the style. Otherwise maybe using the TimeManager plugin.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this in qgis2web. You could use a categorized renderer to hide some points, but there is no toggling mechanism. You'd have to code that yourself.